# finite dimensional compact Hausdorff space, not second countable

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

If $X=[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ in product topology, then it is a compact Hausdorff space which is not second countable. However I think this space is infinite in (covering, inductive)dimension. Does there exist a compact Hausdorff space which is not second countable and finite in dimension?

Comment: For compact non-metrisable spaces ind, Ind and dim dimension functions can differ. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X=\omega_1 + 1$ is not second countable, compact and hereditarily normal, and has $\dim(X)=\text{Ind}(X)=0$. I think $0$ counts as finite...

$\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$ also has the same dimension values and is compact and non-second countable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you further explain what is $\omega_{1}+1$? I am not familiar with this space.

Comment: @Ken.Wong The space of all countable ordinals plus compactifying point. Munkres calls it $\overline{S_\Omega}$ IIRC